# Error executing query with table join does not display

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

There is a query that the user has in the bookmarks this product, also considers the product likes and displays all products in the table:

```
SELECT P.*, 
  COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS LIKES, 
  (B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID AND B.USER_ID = B.USER_ID) AS BOOKMARKS 
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P 
      LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON (L.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID) 
      LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON (B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
        GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, B.PRODUCT_ID, B.USER_ID ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID
```

But he adds the product to the existing ones in the product and does not display `false`, but only `true`, and false displays `null` for its place:

```
product_id |  product_name | ... | LIKES | BOOKMARKS |
------------------------------------------------------
     1     |     name 1    | ... |   0   |   true    |
     1     |     name 1    | ... |   0   |   true    |
     2     |     name 2    | ... |   0   |   NULL    |
     3     |     name 3    | ... |   0   |   NULL    |
     4     |     name 4    | ... |   0   |   NULL    |
```

Why does he add me an extra product 1 and does not display a bookmark column `false`, but does it `null`? Where am I wrong help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the knowledge that the `B.PRODUCT_ID` field will be *either* the same value as the `P.PRODUCT_ID`, *or* NULL, you can use [the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) to ask that question instead.

```
SELECT […] (B.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) AS PRODUCT_IS_IN_BOOKMARKS […]
```

---

You are dealing with the [horror of NULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) and [three-value logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL)). NULL makes everything difficult!

> does not display a bookmark column false, but does it null?

Short explanation: NULL is not a value; it is the not-a-value placeholder. Asking “is this value equal to don't-have-a-value?” has no meaningful answer, so SQL dictates the response is NULL.

Longer explanation: Your joins are `LEFT JOIN`, so you are asking for rows *even when* there is nothing on the right side of that join. When there's no corresponding tuple in the BOOKMARKS table, its columns in the result set are NULL. So your computed field `(B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID AND B.USER_ID = B.USER_ID)` will, when there is no corresponding BOOKMARKS record, be comparing for equality with NULL; and so will get the result `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some of `B.PRODUCT_ID`, `P.PRODUCT_ID`, `B.USER_ID` and `B.USER_ID` have the SQL NULL value, so the result is NULL.

“NULL” means “unknown” in SQL.

If you check two things for equality, and one of them is unknown, the result is unknown.

If two conditions have to be true, but the result of one condition is unknown, the total result is unknown.

In short, NULL is “contagious”.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
    B.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT DISTINCT FROM P.PRODUCT_ID
AND B.USER_ID    IS NOT DISTINCT FROM B.USER_ID
```

`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is like `=`, but it treats NULL as if it were a normal value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `coalesce()` for null replace to other unknown id which may never exist in your id  return false 
because null=null checking is not possible

```
SELECT P.*, 
  COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS LIKES, 
  (coalesce(B.PRODUCT_ID,-99999) = P.PRODUCT_ID AND ) AS BOOKMARKS 
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P 
      LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON (L.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID) 
      LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON (B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
        GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, B.PRODUCT_ID, B.USER_ID ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID
```